Get the CRC32 for the entire archive using libZip
I'm looking at a way to determine if two ZIP archives are identical without reading the entire contents.
My idea is to fetch the CRC32 from the central directory and compare the two CRC32s for equality.
But libzip doesn't seem to have a way to fetch the central directory and retrieve the CRC32.
zip_stat would retrieve the CRC32 of one specific file, but I can't figure out how to get the CRC32 of the central directory.

There is no CRC-32 of the central directory stored in the zip file. You could compute them, but at that point you might as well just directly compare the two central directories that you would need to read anyway.
You can find the central directories using the zip format as described in the appnote.
Then you will need to define what you mean by "identical". Do the entries all need to be in same order? Does all of the metadata need to be same?

According to Wikipedia (yes, yes) the Central Directory File Header contains a CRC32.  I (perhaps unwisely) assumed that the CRC32 in the CDFH was the CRC32 of the uncompressed contents of the ZIP file.

Each central directory header contains the CRC of the uncompressed data of that entry. There is no CRC stored in the zip file of the entire central directory, or even of any part of the central directory.

Secondarily, I use 'identical' to mean 'will unzip to the same file structure, with the same contents'.   So there is a lot of metadata that I don't care about, like compression methods, extra headers, entry ordering, modification times, etc.

Then you will need to read and interpret the central directories from both zip files, and build a structure in memory for each, of the path names of the files, their CRCs, and their lengths. Sort both by the path names and compare.

I had assumed that the CRC32 in the Local File Header was the CRC32 of the uncompressed data of the file.   Am I to understand that the CRC32 in the Local File Header is just the CRC of the File Header itself?  Because if that CRC32 is just the File Header, then I need a different approach, as I want to determine "equality" without having to read the entire file.

The CRC in the local header (if present) is equal to the CRC in the central header, and is the CRC of the file when decompressed.

The local header can optionally not have the CRC (or lengths), and defer those to a data descriptor that follows the compressed data. But the CRC is always in the central header for that file.

A zip file can create empty directories, so you may want to also keep track of any directory entries listed in the zip file, which are identified by names ending with a slash, and which will have no contents (zero-length and zero-CRC data).

There are no CRCs stored in the zip file of the local, central, or end headers. The CRCs in the zip file are of the uncompressed data resulting from each entry.
